# Converting a C char array into a Matlab String using Matlab Coder

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

I have some code written in Matlab that I am converting into C code using Matlab Coder.

I have written a C function that I want to call from the generated C code. This works, so far so good.

The problem is that one of the parameters to the C function is a char** used to output a string.

I accomplish this by making an opaque char* and using coder.wref to get the char**. But how do I convert the opaque char* to a Matlab string so I can return it from my function?

The code goes something like this:

```
function [status,out] = cfun()
    buf = coder.opaque('char *', 'NULL');
    len = coder.opaque('size_t ', 'NULL');
    status = 0;
    status = coder.ceval('_cfun', coder.wref(buf), coder.wref(len));

    out = buf; % How do I convert buf into a Matlab string here??
end
```

_cfun will write some data to buf and write the length into len.

My current solution, which almost works, is to manually make a char array in Matlab and transfer to data. Like this:

```
length = cast(len, 'int32');
out = char(zeros(1,length+1));
for i = 1:(length+1)
    out(i) = cast(buf(i), 'int32');
end
```

The C code generated from this makes no sense and loops infinitely, but I can manually update it to work. However this requires a manual update every time I rerun the code generation.

The C code looks like this:

```
i18 = length + 1L;
copyfrom = (int)i18;
i = 1;
while (i <= copyfrom) {
    source_str->data[0] = (signed char)(int)buf;
    i = 2;
}
```

I can update it to work:

```
i18 = length + 1L;
copyfrom = (int)i18;
i = 1;
while (i <= copyfrom) {
    source_str->data[i-1] = (signed char)(int)(buf[i-1]);
    i = i+1;
}
```

So, is there a way to convert the char* + length into a Matlab string? Or is there a better way of doing what I am trying to?

Comment: Curious, Why `L` in `length + 1L;` and all the casts in the C code?  Better to post definitions of `i18, length, copyfrom, i, source_str, buf` to see whats is going on.  As the post stands now,  I find it unclear.

Comment: This is generated code from Matlab. So the L and the casts are Matlab's decision. I think the L is to avoid and check for integer overflow (I removed some checks in the code). The definitions aren't really important unless you want to start debugging why the for loop is not generated correctly. But the answer below works, so I will not spend more time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit wasteful, but you could allocate a MATLAB `char` array and `memcpy` the data into it:

```matlab
mllen = cast(len,'int32'); % or int64
mlbuf = blanks(mllen); % allocate character vector
coder.ceval('memcpy',coder.wref(mlbuf),buf,len);
use(mlbuf);
```

You may want a +1 or -1 on sizes based upon whether or not `len` counts a NULL terminator and if you want it.

If you can somehow figure out `len` before the call to `_cfun` then you can just pass `mlbuf` to `_cfun` and forget the copy.

The generated code is indexing with 0 and producing an infinite loop because as far as Coder is concerned, `buf` is a 1-by-1 `coder.opaque`. You would get an index out of bounds error if you generated a MEX file and ran it.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I can not figure out `len` before the call to `_cfun`, but it works like this, so that's perfect.