# Converting a C char array into a Matlab String [Matlab Coder]

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

My intention is to show for the output of Matlab System a string the type char_T data[ ], that I receive a function in C through coder.ceval

I want to show more specifically the buffer variable, as it would have to declare the buffer variable

```
matlab
function data = stepImpl(obj)
        buffer = ¿¿ ??;

        if coder.target ('Rtw')
            coder.cinclude('File_Wrapper.h');
            coder.ceval('function',obj.port, coder.wref(buffer)); 
            data = ¿¿¿ string(buffer) ???;
        end
end
```

this would be the function sent to me by char_T data[ ], I use coder.wref to fill the variable in the following method

```
void function(uint8_T uartPort, char_T data[])
{
    char buffer[30];
    if (uartPort == 1)
    {
        fgets(buffer, 10, uart1);
    }
    else if (uartPort == 2)
    {
        fgets(buffer, 10, uart2);
    }

    snprintf (data, sizeof(buffer), "%s", buffer);
}
```

This post dont work for me:
[Converting a C char array into a Matlab String using Matlab Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000799/converting-a-c-char-array-into-a-matlab-string-using-matlab-coder)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is going wrong with the code you have written? Do you see any error messages, or get answers different than you expect?

I think that you might run into problems with your 'buffer' variable in MATLAB not being large enough to store everything that you are printing into it in your C code. I would recommend initializing it with 'buffer = blanks(10)' to make sure it can hold at least 10 characters (which is the number I think you are reading). Another good option might be to just use 'fread' instead of your custom C code (if that is possible), as that function is supported for MATLAB Coder.